# Is it possible to find strings that have two @ chars with regex?

Tags: regex

Would like to find and delete email addresses that have 2 @ symbols from a list of emails.

ex.

```
fisrt@last@email.com
```

I have this but I need to only return true if there are 2 @ symbols on the same line:

```
(?s).*?(/(?:.*)(?:\@)(?:.*)@/)|.*
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: updated question

Comment: Something as simple as `/^[^@]*@[^@]*@[^@]*$/gm` should work fine if you ignore the email check. [Regex101](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: @h2ooooooo that will match strings like `dont@@matchme`, which are not a proper email

Comment: I am looking for bad emails.  Trying to remove them from a list.

Comment: If it is Python, and you have `email_list=['email1@domain.com','e@mail2@domain.com']`, you may just use `[x for x in email_list if x.count('@') == 1]` - see [demo](https://ideone.com/Zx5E1V).

Comment: Be aware that `"a@b"@example.com` is valid.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following regex:

```
^(?:[^@]+@){2}[^.]+\.[a-z]+$
```

- `^` Match beginning of string
- `(?:[^@]+@){2}` Match two occurences of anything other than a comma, followed by a comma
- `[^.]+` Match anything other than a dot
- `\.` Match a literal dot
- `[a-z]+` Match any alphabetical character
- `$` Match end of string

---

Live demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/hiOGyW/1)

Comment: This is great help but it will match on different lines.  In your demo if you put dont@matchme.com as the first email it does not work.

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You might use

```
^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[a-z]+$
```

Explanation

- `^` Start of string
- `[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+` Match 2 times 1 or more repetitions of any char except an @ or whitespace char
- `[^\s@]+` Match 1+ times any char except an @ or whitespace char
- `\.[a-z]+` Match a dot and 1+ times a char a-z
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iaigM0/1/)